# EC2 GPU instance (p3.2xlarge) failing after creating its AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a p3.2xlarge instance with Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu). I have installed various packages on it. I also attached EFS to this machine. Now, I wanted to implement autoscaling so I created image from this instance. Now the instances launched from the AMI and the original instance seem to stuck at same point. When I go to the original instance's screenshot, this is the last line:
[22.675975] systemd-journald [464] : Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1

Comment: Jawad, it may be that your /etc/fstab is wrong or your file systems are corrupt or taking a long time to fsck.

I'd recreate the AMI from scratch.  Be sure to test a few reboots beforehand.

Comment: /etc/fstab seems fine when I attached this volume to a temporary instance. Shows LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs / ext4 defaults,discard 0 0. And there is nothing else here. Do you suggest anything to add or remove?

Comment: Does that LABEL exist?  You can use the `lsblk -f` command to check

Comment: Yes the label exists and lsblk -f  returns cloudimg-rootfs as label

Comment: Hmm.  Have you tried running `fsck` on it?  And confirmed that it is actually ext4?

Comment: Or change to use UUID rather than LABELs.

This may be helpful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-booting-from-wrong-volume.html

Comment: No. I have attached the volume as /dev/sdf to a temp machine. Tell me the commands that I can run so that when I remount it to original instance as /dev/sda1, it must boot. Thanks!

Comment: Adding UUID didn't work. Still clueless. Should I go for technical support?

Comment: Yeah, I'm out of ideas.  Sorry!

Comment: *"and the original instance seem to stuck"* Wait, the original instance is broken, too?  Creating an AMI from an instance does not change anything about the source instance, so if this is happening on the original instance, the problem was latent there and is unrelated to the AMI creation process.

Comment: Creating the AMI resulted in the original instance going broken. Otherwise it was all good. The moment I created image, the terminal is dead and I had to restart it and finally got the error